# Select last record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want select only records from most ID that contain the situation = 'A'.

If the record contains more IDs with the situation = ' C ' can not return anything ;

How to do this ?

```
select * from tabela a where 
a.id not in (select max(b.id) from tabela b where b.fk=a.fk and b.situacao='A')
```

[image]

Comment: This is not clear.  How can a situation be both A and C?

Comment: How about adding sample data with desired output

Comment: MA4IDODE is ID (PK);
MA4IDOCO is FK;
MA4IDSIT is a situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. The inner query just gets all the ma4idoco's that are `C` and just exclude all of them first. If I understand the question correctly there could be multiple rows with the same ma4idoco and ma4idsit = 'A' but you want the max ma4idode.

```
SELECT MAX(a.ma4idode),
  a.ma4idoco,
  a.ma4idsit
FROM tablea a
WHERE a.ma4idoco NOT IN (SELECT b.ma4idoco FROM tablea b WHERE b.ma4idsit = 'C')
  AND a.ma4idsit = 'A'
GROUP BY a.ma4idoco, a.ma4idsit
```